# Hadoop EMR - Physical memory error when compressing with 4mz (zstd)

Tags: hadoop, compression, emr

I have a problem with my hadoop cluster running in AWS EMR.

When I run my cluster steps with a compression of lzo or bz2 everything works fine. The thing is that I wanted a better compression that can also handle splits so I went to use 4mz (or zstd) from https://github.com/carlomedas/4mc.

Now when I run my cluster, it fails with an error:
`... is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 4.6 GB of 4 GB physical memory used; 6.3 GB of 20 GB virtual memory used. Killing container. ...`

I tried increasing the memory using `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` but it still fails (only later in time ... looks like the reducer completes some more compressions before it fails).

I wonder why using this new compression type makes my cluster fail?

My cluster:
8 instances of c4.xlarge

Thanks!